# How to generate editable drawing of connected shapes in Java

Tags: java, svg, drawing

Can anybody tell me how I could do the following:

I want my Java code to generate a drawing that has multiple connected shapes.  Perhaps hundreds of shapes--not huge.  I'd like to generate this and save it as a standard file format that somebody could open in a viewer or an editor.  I do not want to implement viewing or editing logic--generation only.

I'd like the user to be able to take my generated file, open it in a WYSIWYG editor, and move the shapes around with the lines that connect the shapes staying connected to the shapes as they move.  That way, my generation code does not have to be super smart about making sure that connectors don't overlap.

Can anybody suggest a combination of file format, Java library, editor (or some subset of those three) that would work well for this task?

Thoughts so far:

1. yEd allows this editing behavior and uses graphml as the format.  However, I'm not sure how widely used graphml is, and I'm concerned about availability of glyphs.
2. Inkscape and SVG are widely used, but I'm a complete novice, and so far I haven't been able to get lines to stay connected to other shapes using Inkscape when I move them around.

I'm open to other options...

Comment: I'd recommend going with SVG in any case.  However, I don't know if it natively supports some sort of 'grouping' operator like you want.  Otherwise, without writing the editor yourself, you have no control over how it interprets your data.

Comment: FYI: you can add custom SVG glyphs in yEd, though I'm not sure if it can be done programmatically.